# Calculating an object's position, velocity and other derivatives of motion efficiently

Tags: java, physics, motion

OK, here's a programming/physics puzzle in, let's say Java (although it doesn't really matter - but for consistency, we will use Java).

I have an array of doubles where each element represents the successive derivates of an object's position. So:

```
d[0] // position
d[1] // velocity
d[2] // accelleration
```

etc ...

There will be at least 1 and potentially any number of elements (but in practice, probably not more than 5). All elements beyond the end of the array are assumed to be zero.

We also have a `double t` for time.

So if `d.length` were 3 then very specifically:

```
d[0] += d[1] * t + d[2] * t * t / 2
d[1] += d[2] * t
```

But how can we write an iterative solution (no recursion!) that will update all of the elements of the array for time t for any length of a?

Votes should be awarded for efficiency and conciseness.

EDIT: 
The laws of motion are on the physics pages of this site, but basically
each term has the form:

```
power(t,n) / factorial(n)
```

So the next term of the first equation would be `d[3] * t*t*t / 6`

If you are not familiar with these equations, please don't ask me to explain.

A test case:

```
final static double[] D = { 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0 };
double t = 10.0
```

should give:

```
[945.0, 300.66666666666663, 73.0, 12.0, 1.0]
```

Second element may vary due to precision errors.

Comment: Please, can you update your question showing an example with a.length == 3?

Comment: So are asking about an integration scheme? do you have a fixed time step?

Comment: Should have been length == 3. Change to d for array name so as not to confuse it with acceleration. t is obviously not fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far. I am going to leave it open for a bit to see if anything really interesting pops up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this works.

```
int length = d.length;
for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
    double temp = 0;
    for (int j = length - 1; j > i; j--)
        temp = (temp + d[j]) * t / (j - i);
    d[i] += temp;
}
```

Comment: This gives slightly worse rounding errors than the other solutions: [945.0, 300.66666666666674, 73.0, 12.0, 1.0]

Comment: @rghome It will do yes. The way to calculate powers like `t * t * t * t * t` accurately is to use `Math.pow` (because each successive multiplication introduces another error). So if you want accuracy you actually can't reuse previously calculated answers for `t`, `t * t`, `t * t * t`, `t * t * t * t`. If accuracy is what you want, I don't think you can do better than calculate each of `t`, `t * t / 2`, `t * t * t / 6` from scratch, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I got smaller rounding errors doing the divide first, but maybe that will depend on the test case.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

```
for (int i = 0; i < d.length - 1; i++) {
    d[i] = 0;
    int f = 1;
    double p = 1;
    for (int j = i+1; j < d.length; j++) {
        f *= j - i;
        p *= t;
        d[i] += d[j] * p / f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Up-vote for the first answer, but I reckon it should be possible to avoid recalculating the factorial and the power in the inner loop at least. Maybe even in the outer loop.